# Picking elements from a list

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to improve my understanding of lists in NetLogo. 
Shortly, I am adding and picking (and removing) items from lists. Each turtle has its own list. 
Each list should contain items in a chronological order, from the most recent to the oldest. Once a turtle chooses an item, the neighbours have this item on the top of their lists (same for the turtle that chooses the item). What I tried to do is:

```
rnd:weighted-one-of-list mylist [ [ii] -> ii ] ; pick one of the most recent items already in the list
set mylist lput old_item mylist print "Old item" ; add items to the list
```

using the extension as JenB suggested in a previous post.
Condition to use pick an item from a list (old item) is that mylist is not empty (`if empty? mylist`).
My question is if it is correct to pick an item using the extension in that way as I did.

UPDATE: The list is made up in the following way: 
I decide to create a new item, `item 4` with `quality 2` (quality is a parameter in `[0,5]`).
I add this item in my list `(item 4, item3, item2, item1)` - from the most recent to the oldest - with quality `item4 2, item3 1, item2 2, item1 5`, respectively, and in neighbours' lists: `neighbour1`, for example, would have list `(item4, item 11, item 10,..)` with `quality 2, 3, 1`, respectively.
What I would expect is to pick an item from the list based on the quality parameter. This would mean that I would pick `item1` from mylist. My neighbours would pick `item11` as it has quality equal to 3, i.e. the highest in its group.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `random-float 1 < 2` is always true, since a number between 0 and 1.0 is always less than 2.

Comment: My apologies, Seth! It was not proportional to 2, but to a parameter that can take values from 0 to 1. I edited the post. It was a lapse (but I did twice)

Comment: `random-float 1 < a` looks correct to me.

Comment: Thanks Seth. My doubts have been regarding the words “proportional to”. Do you think it is correct to interpret it as I did? And last, but not least as this was mainly the question, is it correct to add and pick items using the extension as shown in the part of code that I posted? JenB gave me some suggestions on how to use it, and I wanted to be sure that this is the way (I am not getting any error, so it is difficult for me to understand it). Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to either of those questions.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. What weights are you using? You talk about the list having items that you want to select, but how does this 'parameter' you mention relate to weights? Is it just a true/false switch or is it some sort of multiplier? You need to give us an example list, an example parameter and tell us what output you expect.

Comment: I edited the question just a bit to better explain what I would need to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/rnd.html

> ```
> rnd:weighted-one-of-list mylist [ [ii] -> ii ]
> ```
>
> is it correct to pick an item using the extension in that way?

Yes, that is a correct usage, according to the documentation.